# Date format for Spanish speakers - returning NaN or Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I have an Angular application

**Goal**: I want a user to be able to type in Spanish format for a date (DD/MM/YYYY). It should display in Spanish format to the user, but convert it back to English behind-the-scenes when sending the data to the Database

**Problem**: If they type something larger than 12 for the first 2 digits, then JavaScript Date complains that it's NaN.

**What I tried**: I looked up documentation and found the method `toLocaleDateString` and `toLocaleString`. However this is used on a Date. And if a date becomes **NaN** then I don't see how the method would work? I tried it out anyways but it just says ***Invalid Date {}***
I am in central time zone if it matters.

**TypeScript**:

```
dateEnter(data) {
    let dateSpanish = new Date(data).toLocaleDateString;
    let dobForDB = (this.localeId == "es") ? this.myMethod(new Date(dateSpanish) : data;
}

myMethod(date: any) {
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let day = date.getDate();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let dateString = (this.localeId == "es") ? day.toString() + "/" + month.toString() + "/" + year.toString().substring(0, 4) : month.toString() + "/" + day.toString() + "/" + year.toString().substring(0, 4);
    return dateString;
}
```

Comment: Note that running `new Date(stringValue)` with anything other than a few specific formats is likely to cause problems. Split the string on known good delimiters and pass the parts to the Date constructor.

Comment: What does "*…but convert it back to English behind-the-scenes…*" mean? If you're transmitting dates as strings, then ISO 8601 formats are likely the most widely compatible. Date objects don't have a format, they're just a time value that is converted to a date string for human comprehension.

Comment: @RobG it means that if the user is a spanish speaker and enters 25/12/2019 I want it to show in the database as 12/25/2019 (or more specifically, 2019-12-25). If the Month and Date was flipped the data would be corrupted. Also, If the user enters a number larger than 12, the javascript Date complains.

Comment: @angleUr—the usual solution is to 1. Tell users the expected format 2. present the parsed date value to the user in an unambiguous format 3. do not use the built–in parser (i.e. `new Date(string)`, use your own parse function or a library. Most large booking sites don't allow entering a date, they just present a date picker (which I find annoying but understand why they do it). Most databases want ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD) or something unambiguous likeDD-MMM-YYYY, e.g. 23-Dec-2019. Guessing the format from navigator.language and parsing based on that is likely the worst way to go about it.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up not using Date(string) to parse, I just made my own and it seems to work. If you want to include this in an answer I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for this scenario. It can detect the user's locale settings.  Use the `L` format specifier to work with the short date for the locale.

```
moment("01/02/2019", "L").format("YYYY-MM-DD")

// Output in en-US:  "2019-01-02"  (January 2nd)
// Output in es-MX:  "2019-02-01"  (February 1st)
```

Keep in mind that it's not just language that determines the format.  There are plenty of English-speaking locales that use `DD/MM/YYYY` formats.  The United Kingdom is one example.  It's primarily the United States (`en-US`) that use `MM/DD/YYYY`.  see [Date Format by Country on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country).

Comment: "There are plenty of English-speaking locales that use DD/MM/YYYY". I would say all of them, except one. ;-)